# Minimizing SELECT latency in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

I am evaluating Postgres 9.4 performance on a machine with Intel i7 quad-core 3.6 GHz CPU, 8 GB ram, and 7400 rpm HDD (no RAID) running Linux Mint. The DB schema has the following table:

```
          Table "public.sensor_readings"
  Column  |           Type           | Modifiers
----------+--------------------------+-----------
 time     | timestamp with time zone | not null
 value    | numeric                  |
 sensor_id| integer                  | not null

Indexes:
      "sensor_readings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (sensor_id, "time")
```

This table has 72 million rows and is 35 GB in size (PKEY index is 25 GB). `sensor_id` ranges from 0 to 5000.
I need to query sensor values for past two weeks:

```
SELECT 
FROM sensor_readings 
WHERE sensor_id IN (1,3,8,9,12) 
    AND time BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '14 day' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

The problem is that the average query execution time is about 5 minutes even after a 2000-execution warm up. This is two orders of magnitude higher that what I want to achieve!

I did not change Postgres default parameters and did no optimization.

Can anyone suggest what can be wrong with my setup or schema? Are there any optimizations that I can do to minimize `SELECT` execution time? In particular, what is a proper ratio between table (index?) size and RAM?

P.S.

Sample EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on sensor_readings  (cost=3535.18..405031.07 rows=113904 width=0) (actual time=5190.213..60196.531 rows=103104 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((sensor_id = ANY ('{1509,1504,1503,1500,1502}'::integer[])) AND ("time" >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '14 days'::interval)) AND ("time" <= ('now'::cstring)::date))
  Heap Blocks: exact=47786
  Buffers: shared hit=12 read=48491
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sensor_readings_pkey  (cost=0.00..3506.70 rows=113904 width=0) (actual time=5165.932..5165.932 rows=103750 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((sensor_id = ANY ('{1509,1504,1503,1500,1502}'::integer[])) AND ("time" >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '14 days'::interval)) AND ("time" <= ('now'::cstring)::date))
        Buffers: shared hit=12 read=705

Planning time: 24.887 ms
Execution time: 60205.108 ms
```

Comment: Do you have an index over time?

Comment: you did not edit postgresql.conf memory parameters ?. Those are set so low that you can start postgresql on an old pentium class machine.

Comment: @Renzo: No. I do not have an index on time. I only have the primary key.

Comment: @simplexio: I wanted to increase shared_buffers but then I read on many blogs that the parameter should not be increased more than a few hundred MBs because OS file cache will take care of the caching.

Comment: How big (in physical size) is this table?  You mention below that you are updating it continuously - or you mean inserts there?

Comment: I meant inserts. The table size is 35 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you have 60 GB of data which you want to access quickly on a single slow HDD (I've never heard of 7400 rpm, is it 5400 or 7200?).

You can partition on the time, so the last two weeks of data are grouped together in tight set.

Or you could try clustering on the time instead of partitioning on it.  You could either build on index on the date column, cluster on that, then drop the index; or you could just make a new table by `create table asdfkj as select * from sensor_readings order by time`.

I would expect the table to already be pretty well clustered on time, but it doesn't seem to be.  How did this table get populated originally?  How does it get kept up to date now?

But all of these methods are pretty expensive (in your time) to avoid buying a better IO system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is just a test setup and not the final deployment environment. Can a better IO bridge the two orders of magnitude gap by a factor of ten let's say?
The table was populated by values that were sorted over time and is updated continuously by new reading with the current time stamp.

Comment: Toy setups are good for development, but horrible for performance tuning.  Any thing you change to get better performance on a toy system might do nothing, or even be counterproductive, when carried over to the real system.  If the drives are 2 times faster and you have 5 times more of them, and the controller is smarter about scheduling things, and you they have larger on-board caches, 10 times is not out of the question.  Also, if your table is already well clustered on time, then the current performance seems pathologically broken even for a single slow drive.  Is it failing sectors?

Comment: The disk was the major bottleneck here. I moved my setup to another machine with RAID and SSD read cache; everything else is similar. Now the performance is as good as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create an index on `time`, and see if this improves the execution time of your query:

```
CREATE INDEX time_index ON sensor_readings(time);
```

An alternative is to partition or cluster the table on `time`, as described in another answer.

Comment: This partial index won't work: _ERROR:  functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE_

Comment: So, try building a full index to see if the execution time improves.

Comment: You may want to redact your post ;)